# about unix command "sed"

Tags: unix, sed

I want to do the following substitution in a text file:

the original string: `"---a---"`

after substitution : `"---\a---"`

and I run the following command:

```
sed -r -e "s/-(a)-/-\\\1-/g" test.txt
```

but it doesn't give the right result. What command args should I use?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have mistakenly deleted an answer. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that backslashes are significant in Bash's double-quoted strings as well as in sed itself. Either use single quotes:

```
sed -r -e 's/-(a)-/-\\\1-/g' test.txt
```

Or escape the backslashes again:

```
sed -r -e "s/-(a)-/-\\\\\\1-/g" test.txt
```

If you echo the strings, you'll see what's happening:

```
$ echo "s/-(a)-/-\\\1-/g"
s/-(a)-/-\\1-/g
$ echo 's/-(a)-/-\\\1-/g'
s/-(a)-/-\\\1-/g
$ echo "s/-(a)-/-\\\\\\1-/g"
s/-(a)-/-\\\1-/g
```

The first one (your original) just looks like a literal backslash followed by a literal 1 to sed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sed -r -e "s/-(a)-/-\\\\\\1-/g"` or `sed -r -e 's/-(a)-/-\\\1-/g'`

The problem is that `\` is captured by bash if you use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

With `"` you will have to do something like:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "---a---" | sed -r "s/-(a)-/-\\\\\1-/g"
---\a---
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to replace 1 with a

```
sed -r -e "s/-(a)-/-\\\a-/g" test.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

so many answers ......

```
Kaizen ~/so_test 
$ echo "---a---" | sed -n 's/a/\\a/p'
---\a---
```

since you have a text file the following should work :

```
  sed -i 's/a/\\a/g' filename.txt ;
```

does this help ?